# Undefined references when using g++ to compile a program dependent on FreeType library

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, freetype

I'm currently working on a makefile for my gamedev project, and have managed to compile everything into a static lib `bingus.a` - my engine. I am now trying to build an example program but I am discovering that my FreeType static lib is not linking correctly.

Here is the output of the make command

```
C:\Projects\Games\bingus>make examples
g++ -o hello_window -Wall -Iinclude -Isrc examples/hello_window.cpp bingus.a -Llib -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lfreetype
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x234d): undefined reference to `FT_New_Face'
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x23b2): undefined reference to `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x23ee): undefined reference to `FT_Load_Char'
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x25f0): undefined reference to `FT_Load_Char'
bingus.a(renderer.o):renderer.cpp:(.text+0x281f): undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello_window] Error 1
```

Below is the entire contents of my Makefile

```
# Define target platform
PLATFORM    ?= DESKTOP
 
# Define paths
SOURCE_PATH ?= src
INCLUDE_PATH    ?= include
LIB_PATH    ?= lib
EXAMPLES_PATH   ?= examples
OUTPUT_PATH ?= out
 
#Define includes
BINGUS_INCLUDES =   -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) \
            -I$(SOURCE_PATH)
 
#Define engine object files
BINGUS_SRCS =   $(SOURCE_PATH)/bingus.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/debug.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/entity.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/glad.c \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/input.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/math.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/renderer.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/shader.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/texture.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/ui.cpp \
        $(SOURCE_PATH)/window.cpp

BINGUS_OBJS =   bingus.o \
        debug.o \
        entity.o \
        glad.o \
        input.o \
        math.o \
        renderer.o \
        shader.o \
        texture.o \
        ui.o \
        window.o

# Define compiler vars
CC = g++
AR = ar
CFLAGS = -Wall

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), WEB)
    # Compile with emscripten - untested as yet
    CC = emcc
    AR = emar
endif

bingus.a: $(BINGUS_OBJS)
    $(AR) cr $@ $^
 
bingus.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/bingus.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
debug.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/debug.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
entity.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/entity.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
glad.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/glad.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
input.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/input.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
math.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/math.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
renderer.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/renderer.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
shader.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/shader.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
texture.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/texture.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
ui.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/ui.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
window.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/window.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c $(BINGUS_INCLUDES)
 
examples: hello_window
 
hello_window: $(EXAMPLES_PATH)/hello_window.cpp bingus.a
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(BINGUS_INCLUDES) $^ -L$(LIB_PATH) -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lfreetype
```

I have tried checking the order of arguments in the g++ command but the order seems correct to me. All the libs I am trying to link to were compiled separately using Visual Studio. My libraries are located under the lib/ folder in my project dir, and are named `libglfw3.a` and `libfreetype.a` - glfw does not throw linking errors so presumably is working fine.

Comment: "_were compiled separately using Visual Studio_": Are you really trying to use GCC to link libraries compiled with Visual Studio? Or do you mean Visual Studio Code (a completely different program)?

Comment: It may be necessary to specify a library multiple times. Try adding another `-lfreetype` at the end.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, the libraries were compiled using Visual Studio not G++, I was not aware this would be a problem... I tried adding -lfreetype to the end as well but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Unless two compilers (or two versions of the same compiler) explicitly state that they are binary compatible, you should assume that they are not. In general, *all* components of a C++ program (your sources + any libraries etc) need to be compiled with the *exact same* compiler and the *same* compiler options. You generally cannot mix and match objects compiled with different compilers, compiler versions or compilation options (like trying to mix debug and release builds for example).

Comment: Just a note that most of Jesper's comment doesn't apply on POSIX systems such as GNU/Linux and MacOS: you can generally freely mix and match code compiled with GCC and Clang, and code compiled with and without debugging and different optimization levels.  If you are using Visual Studio C++ then you do have to be very deliberate about matching up these things, and since VS C++ doesn't necessarily use the same naming conventions as GCC and Clang you may have issues linking them together if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggested, the problem was that I was attempting to include libs compiled with a different compiler. By using MinGW to compile all dependencies I was able to fix the problem.